# Difficult inequality : $\sum_{n} |z_{n}|\le \pi \left|\sum_{k} z_{n_k}\right|$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Given a family of complex numbers $(z_n)_n$ prove that there exists a subsequence $(z_{n_k})_k$ such that

$$\sum_{n} |z_{n}|\le \pi \left|\sum_{k} z_{n_k}\right|$$

I ailled to find a counter example of this inequality. what tricky me here is the constant $\pi$. How does that constant appears here? How can I prove this inequality?

Any hint or idea?

Comment: Restricted to reals, you could get a constant of 2 by considering the negative sums and the positive sums (and then taking the bigger sum in absolute value as your subsequence); maybe something similar could work here? (never took complex analysis so I don't have any other ideas, and no clue where pi comes from)

Comment: The pointed-to question is about an estimate with factor $4 \sqrt 2$ (which is easier to obtain), but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91961/42969) proves it with factor $\pi$ (and argues that $\pi$ is the best possible factor).

Comment: And here is the generalization to higher dimensions: [Maximum subset sum of $d$-dimensional vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102508/maximum-subset-sum-of-d-dimensional-vectors)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1211768/42969) is the same solution, but with an instructive comment: *"Trying to find a subset with largest sum, it is evident that the best thing you can do is to take those vectors which lie in some half-plane."*