# What is $\sup_\limits{E\subset[-\pi,\pi)}\left|\int_Ee^{it}\,dt\right|$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I couldn't think of a descriptive title other than the problem statement itself.  What is $$\sup_\limits{E\subset[-\pi,\pi)}\left|\int_Ee^{it}\,dt\right|?$$

(The question seems possibly relevant to determining  the best constant in the inequalities in my answer
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229714/prove-that-if-lim-n-mua-mua-uniformly-for-all-measurable-set-then-l/3229732?noredirect=1#comment6644944_3229732).)

Comment: well it's certainly not bigger than $2\pi$, but of course you knew that

Comment: @RyleeLyman In fact it's clearly strictly smaller than  $2\pi$, because of cancellation...

Answer (score 3):

Oh. This is simpler than I thought, by an argument not at all like what I  had in mind:

First, replacing $E$ by a translate, wlog $$\int_Ee^{it}\,dt\ge0,$$so in particular $$\left|\int_Ee^{it}\,dt\right|=\int_E\cos(t)\,dt.$$And it's clear that the last integral is maximized by $E=[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Can you expand on your WLOG? It seems like the integral is complex in general, so it's not obvious to me exactly what you mean.

Comment: @preferred_anon If $F$ is $E$ translated by $\theta$ then $\int_F = e^{i\theta}\int_E$. Choose $\theta$ so $e^{i\theta}\int_E\ge0$.

Comment: Ah! And multiplying by $e^{i\theta}$ doesn't change the modulus. Nice!