# An inequality: Can this equality hold?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, pi

See the Lemma 6.3 in RCA by Rudin:

> **Lemma 6.3** Let $z_1$, ... , $z_N$ be complex numbers. Then There is a subset $S$ of $\{1,\,\cdots ,\, z_N\}$ such that
> $$ \left| \sum_{k\in S} z_k \right| \ge \frac {1}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{N} 
> |z_k|.$$

I have an example which shows that the constant $1/\pi$ is sharp.

> **Example.** Let $N$ be an even positive integer. Let $\zeta := e^{2\pi i / N}$ and $z_k := \zeta^k - \zeta ^{k-1}$ for each $k=1, ... , N$. If $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number, then we may say that
> $$ 2-\epsilon < \frac {1}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{N} 
> |z_k| < 2 = \left| \sum_{k=1}^{N/2} z_k \right|$$
> by growing $N$ large enough.

But the equality in Lemma 6.3 does not hold in this case.

**Question:** Is there any example which makes the equality hold?

Comment: It is demonstrated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1211768/42969) that you always have strict inequality.