# Interesting inequality of the modules of the complex numbers: $\bigl|\sum_{j\in J} z_j\bigr|\ge \frac{1}{4\sqrt 2} \sum_{j=1}^n |z_j|.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

The problem

> Let $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n$ be complex numbers. Show that there exists $J\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that $$\left|\sum_{j\in J} z_j\right|\ge \frac{1}{4\sqrt 2} \sum_{j=1}^n |z_j|.$$

My steps: 
I have been trying to solve this problem, my first idea is to do it by induction, which by assuming n = 1 is true, and by taking n+1, playing with the products and analyzing cases, I can get that it is true in some cases, in others I am not sure how to justify it, but my question is if there is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: At least a quarter of the $z_k$ are in one of the four quadrants defined by the lines $x=\pm y$; show that if $w_k$ are in one such quadrant the inequality with only $1/\sqrt 2$ holds considering either the real or imaginary parts and then conclude

Comment: [Searching with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cleft%7C%5Csum_%7Bj%5Cin%20J%7D%20z_j%20%5Cright%7C%5Cge%20%5Cfrac1%7B4%5Csqrt2%7D%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5En%20%7Cz_j%7C%24&p=1) returns this post: [Inequality with complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91939). The [linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/91939) might be of interest, too.